# What does the mathematical symbol with an underline below the variable name mean?

Tags: notation

I have been reading [a research paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00446-004-0112-5). The author has used a variable '$x$' with an underline beneath '$x$'. I know that a variable with a line on top of it implies it's arithmetic mean. But I have never seen a symbol with a line under the variable name. Can anyone please tell what it means?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean $\large{\underline x}$ ? What is the context ?

Comment: Yes. But the paper is related to Linear Programming.

Comment: There is no universal meaning for underlining of variables.  It would be impossible to guess the meaning without having the paper identified, but almost surely the author defines that notation before using  it.

Comment: "have been reading a research paper" - where? A link would be helpful. Even better, as previously noted, the author surely explained his/her notations somewhere near the paper's beginning.

Comment: @user3708999 Can you scan the context and upload?

Comment: The paper is titled as "ConstantTime Distributed Dominating Set Approximation" by Fabian Kuhn and Roger Wattenhofer

Comment: Unfortunately the author did not explain it in the paper. So I thought it must be standard mathematical symbol.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information. I've found a link for you, but you really should have done that yourself.

Comment: Underlining was a fairly common way to denote a vector back in the days before LaTeX, because it's easy to do on a typewriter.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The article has been published in 2005.

Comment: True, but old habits persist.  You tend to use the notation your professors used, or what you saw in the textbooks.

Comment: I don't know about your article, but in one place the authors defined it to be the radical conjugate $$\underline{a+b\sqrt{c}}=a-b\sqrt{c}.$$ This was to distinguish it from the notation for a complex conjugate. The authors also said that this is unconventional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a notation often means a vector that is a solution of minimization problem in linear programming.

I googled for [another article](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~chaudhur/cs611/Sp07/notes/lec22.pdf) on MDS problem, it uses just ordinary vector notation (see p.4)

Answer (score 3):

It's not an often-used convention, but in physics, matrices are sometimes appended with a double line underneath and vectors a single line underneath. This somewhat unifies the matrix/vector notation without the clumsiness of vector notation (and how to extend that to matrices).

Comment: Your answer gives me a hint that it should be a vector. It fits in the context. Thanks.

Comment: The fact that it's easy to use this notation in handwriting makes it very popular, I think.

Answer (score 3):

In the article linked below, it seems it is used to mean the minimum possible value of the variable, while the same variable with a line above it means the maximum possible value of the variable.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221107546_On_Decision_Making_under_Interval_Uncertainty_A_New_Justification_of_Hurwicz_Optimism-Pessimism_Approach_and_its_Use_in_Group_Decision_Making

Answer (score 0):

My teacher (Statistics) said it is a symbol representing the series of observations$$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\ldots$$in order to reduce space and time.

Comment: It looks like my Statistics lecturer uses it for the same.